# Why cannot I see the options menu button?

Tags: android, eclipse, menu, emulation

I'm using android in eclipse. I made an application for this versions.

In my AndroidManifest.

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

I made a tipical menu with four items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@+id/preferences"
    android:title="@string/preferences"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences">
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/galery"
    android:title="@string/galery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery">
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/send"
    android:title="@string/send"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload">
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/Camera"
    android:title="@string/camera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera">
</item>
</menu>
```

If I use for example to 15 version, I have the menu button, and if I push it I can see my menu.
But my problema is with Jelly Bean version, because the emulator don't have any buttons, and the new mobiles phone neither, because they have a button in the screen with three dots, like that.

http://www.blocketpc.com/imagenes/android_ics_menu.png

Should I configure something in my xml files, or I have to configure something in my eclipse emulator?
I want to see these dots in my emulator too. And I don't want to active the hardware keyboard, because in the real life you don't have these buttons.
I'm using galaxy nexus emulator with the 17 version.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is phasing out the Menu button and moving towards using the ActionBar. That should be the problem in your case. Here is a good article that has the information.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Comment: What would you recommend me, Action Bar or Menu with targetSdkVersion 13?
Thaks for the answer!

Comment: If you app is new and you need to use new features, I would go with ActionBar. In the event that you may have to support earlier versions and you really don't have to use anything new from Jelly bean then it is better you keep the version to 13. Hope that helps you decide :-)